# Template repeat change id

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I change the id of the div inside the template in polymer?

I tried this but it put the id to be the string "{{item}}"

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{days}}" as="day">
     <div id="{{item}}"></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `as`, shouldn't it be `{{day.item}}`? See [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#nesting-templates).

In addition, to change the property in the DOM, not just JS, use `$=` instead of `=`. See [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding).